# after installing ubuntu 13.04 CD-ROM not working

Tags: mount, disk, bios, cd-drive

I remove my windows 7 and install ubuntu 13.04 amd64 in EFI after many hit and trail. first time i install ubuntu with DVD and it is success full installation but i decide to install in EFI. in second install i found my CD drive not working (i try ubuntu and w7 cd but not boot) then i use live pen drive and successfully install in EFI. but still cd drive not work. i know it is function and i burn 3 dvd before trying ubuntu and from ubuntu i can eject it and also found in `Disks` utility. but still it not read any CD/DVD and i also try all the questions available here.

output from lshw

```
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVD A  DS8A5LH
         vendor: hp
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: 1H68
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

now what to do please help... (i am on HP probook 4530s. And it is not possible for me to get a usb cd drive or replace it)